# Reshaping block in data.frame to lists is columns uneven length

Tags: r, casting, dataframe, reshape2, melt

I would need your help with R to cast this data:

```
    STATUS     SCORE  JOB.ID 
1   STATUS1    99     JOB1
2   STATUS1    99     JOB2 
3   STATUS1    99     JOB3
4   STATUS1    99     JOB4
5   STATUS2    36     JOB5
6   STATUS2    36     JOB6
7   STATUS2    49     JOB7
8   STATUS2    58     JOB8
9   STATUS2    64     JOB9
```

to this wide form:

```
    STATUS1   STATUS2
1   JOB1      JOB6
2   JOB2      JOB7
3   JOB3      JOB8
4   JOB4      JOB9
5   JOB5      <NA>
```

I do not need to compute a value, I just need to make lists. Ideally the score would be used to sort the resulting lists. The columns length are uneven. I am unable to find an elegant answer elsewhere. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to put that into a data frame. Keeping them as separate lists... `list_em <- by(df$JOB.ID,df$STATUS,unique)` assuming you have `factor`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really do want them all in a single data frame, you could do something like this:

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
dat <- read.table(text = "    STATUS     SCORE  JOB.ID 
 1   STATUS1    99     JOB1
 2   STATUS1    99     JOB2 
 3   STATUS1    99     JOB3
 4   STATUS1    99     JOB4
 5   STATUS2    36     JOB5
 6   STATUS2    36     JOB6
 7   STATUS2    49     JOB7
 8   STATUS2    58     JOB8
 9   STATUS2    64     JOB9",header = TRUE,sep = "")
> dat <- ddply(dat,.(STATUS),transform,ind = seq_along(STATUS))
> dcast(dat,ind~STATUS,fill = NA,value.var = "JOB.ID")
  ind STATUS1 STATUS2
1   1    JOB1    JOB5
2   2    JOB2    JOB6
3   3    JOB3    JOB7
4   4    JOB4    JOB8
5   5    <NA>    JOB9
```

Comment: Amazing thank you. Extra point for correcting my typo putting JOB5 in the wrong column.

Comment: @MichaelRobert Glad I could help. If this answer helped you, please give back to the site that solved your problem by learning about voting and accepting answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).